# Mocking subsequent calls to a method with one of the two argument same

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

In a method I need to unit test, following is the situation:

```java
Predicate<MyClass> predicate1 = (MyClass myClass) -> myClass.getX().equals(SOME_VALUE);

List<MyClass> targets = this.filterMyClass(listOfMyClass, predicate1);

if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(targets)) {
    Predicate<MyClass> predicate2 = (MyClass myClass) -> myClass.getX().equals(SOME_OTHER_VALUE);
    targets = this.filterMyClass(listOfMyClass, predicate2);
}
```

As can be seen, `filterMyClass()` is called two times with first argument the same (a list) while second argument is different (a predicate).

How can calls to filterMyClass be mocked?

Comment: filterMyClass is only called once in the code you posted. But anyway, `thenReturn()`allows specifying multiple results: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.2/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenReturn-T-T...-

Comment: I have modified my post. Also, can thenReturn() allow multiple results when spy is involved.

Comment: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-. Why don't you read the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

```
Mockito.when(myClass.getX).thenReturn(SOME_VALUE, SOME_OTHER_VALUE)
```

this will return SOME_VALUE for first invocation and SOME_OTHER_VALUE for second invocation.